# Exception message, filling a datatable with SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter

I run a simple query to SQL and can't seem to get it working correctly.

```
 DataTable loDTDOffre = new DataTable();
 SqlCommand loSQLCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.SP_StoredProc", loConnectionBD.ConnectionSql);
 loSQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 loSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@liNoUnit", SqlDbType.Int);
 loSQLCommand.Parameters["@liNoUnit"].Value = noUniteProduction;

 SqlDataAdapter loSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(loSQLCommand);

 loSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = loSQLCommand;
 loSqlDataAdapter.Fill(loDTDOffre);
```

My database connection is open, the stored proc executed in SQL Management Studio works fine. All I get as error message in VS2010 is :

```
Warning: Fatal error 50000 occurred at May 30 2013 11:17AM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.
Process ID 59 has raised user error 50000, severity 20. SQL Server is terminating this process.
```

Is there any way to get a clearer message of what is wrong, the code seems right. The error message is so general, I can't figure out what I do wrong.

My stored procedure returns a simple select, one row.

Thanks

Comment: It couldn't hurt to see the stored procedure.  I'm curious if there is a `raiseerror` clause in there that might be causing this.

Comment: Actually I think the problem is that you are assigning a `StoredProcedure` command type to a `SelectCommand`.  I would try ditching your `SqlDataAdapter` and replacing it with `loDTDOffre.Load(loSQLCommand.ExecuteReader());`

Comment: If I run the SQL Profiler, I see my query (stored proc), execute it from SQL Studio, it all works. I have one "raiseerror" in my stored proc but the line is never reached. No inner exception in VS2010, trying to have more details on the exception, the "ExecuteReader" example didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it runs on an approle, this came out :

The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'thisTable', database 'thisDatabase', schema 'dbo'.

Fixed, thank you.